# Excel VBA loop reading cells issues

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, error-handling

I'm new to Excel VBA, but I can't find a solution for this issue.

I'm trying to create a  FOR EACH loop which reads floats inside a range. Inside this loop i should understand if the floats in the cell are 0s or floats greater than 0 and, in the second scenario, put this float in a list/array.

the function should return the first number of the list or 0, if in the range there aren't any floats greater than 0.

in a python env, the code would look like this:

```
rng = list of floats in the range

empty_list = []

for element in rng:

   if element>0:

      empty_list.append(element)

if len(empty_list)>0:

   return empty_list[0]

if len(empty_list)==0:

   return 0
```

what I wrote so far in VBA:

```
Function getNumber()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ArrayLen As Integer
    Dim arr() As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    
    ReDim arr(1)
    
    counter = 0
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell > 0 Then
            arr(counter) = cell.Value
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    ArrayLen = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
    If ArrayLen = 0 Then
        getNumber = 0
    End If
    
    If ArrayLen > 0 Then
        getNumber = 10
    End If
    
End Function
```

Thanks in advance to anybody!

Comment: The "getNumber = 10" is just for debugging issues

Comment: Do you have a specific need to create the list? If the function just returns the first number of the list, why not just exit after a valid first value is found? Do you want to create the list for other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in VBA don't really have an equivalent to `list.append`. One option is resize an array as needed using `ReDim`, but it's an expensive operation and should be done sparingly.

You don't even need an array though:

```
Function getNumber(ByVal rng As Range) As Double
    If WorksheetFunction.Countifs(rng, ">0") = 0 Then Exit Function

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value > 0 Then
           getNumber = cell.Value
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had an error which was asking to declare the variable "cell" thus i had to call "Dim cell As Range"

Comment: My mistake for overlooking that, absolutely correct.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what the end goal is, but here you can use the counter to find out how many, or output the array of found numbers somewhere.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Testfunction()
Debug.Print getNumber
End Sub
Function getNumber()
    
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ArrayLen As Integer
    Dim InArray()
    Dim OutArray()
    Dim Counter As Integer
    
    Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
    InArray = Rng
    Counter = 0
    
    For I = 1 To UBound(InArray, 1)
        Debug.Print InArray(I, 1)
        If InArray(I, 1) > 0 Then Counter = Counter + 1
    Next I
    
    ReDim OutArray(1 To Counter)
    Counter = 1
    
    For I = 1 To UBound(InArray, 1)
        If InArray(I, 1) > 0 Then
            OutArray(Counter) = InArray(I, 1)
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If
    Next I
    
    getNumber = UBound(OutArray)
    
'    counter = 0
'    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
'        If Cell.Value > 0 Then
'            arr(counter) = Cell.Value
'            counter = counter + 1
'        End If
'    Next
'
'    ArrayLen = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
'    If ArrayLen = 0 Then
'        getNumber = 0
'    End If
'
'    If ArrayLen > 0 Then
'        getNumber = 10
'    End If
    
End Function
```